# como exportar a pdf una tabla que es el resultado de un formulario en django

Tags: django, pdf

Buenas, estoy haciendo una aplicacion en Django 1.8 y una de las cosas que quiero es que el usuario llene un formulario con ciertos datos de búsqueda, yo proceso todos los datos haciendo una consulta con a mi modelo.object.filter y el resultado de esa consulta la devuelvo en un html en modo de tabla. yo quisiera una vez que el usuario recibe su respuesta en la tabla, el tenga la opcion de exportar a pdf ese resultado. 
Si alguien me pudiera decir como hacer o dejarme algún link lo agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo usar algo como [Reportlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) del lado del backend, al igual que existen muchas herramientas para generar pdf del lado del front, otra que me gusto mucho es [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/), que es demasiado diferente de trabajar con reportlab, solo que reportlab es recomendado por el mismo django

Comment: Hola Grace. Bienvenid@ a Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor, revisa esta guía __[mcve]__, donde verás que eres tú quien debe proporcionar el ejemplo que ayude a comprender tu problema. Si  necesitas ideas, opiniones o enlaces, te recomiendo que uses Google. Si buscas módules, te recomiendo [__Django Packages__](https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Una manera sencilla de dar al usuario pdf es usar la herramienta wkhtmltopdf. Como su propio nombre indica pasa el html a pdf, con lo que no tendrás que reescribir estilos.

http://django-wkhtmltopdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Un ejemplo que podries usar con tu html actual:

En tus urls:

```
from foo.views import MyPDFView

url(r'^pdf/',MyPDFView.as_view(), name='productes' ),
```

y en tu vista:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse

class MyPDFView(View):
    template='foo.html'

    foo1 = ....
    foo2 = ....

    context= {'foo1': productes, 'foo2':foo2 }

    def get(self, request):
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                       template=self.template,
                                       header_template='header.html',
                                       footer_template='footer.html',
                                       filename="foopdf.pdf",
                                       context= self.context,
                                       show_content_in_browser=False,
                                       cmd_options={'margin-top': 25,},
                                       )
        return response
```